# Absolute Path Not working for create react app with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

If I use absolute path which configured with typescript it doesn't work. After adding config in tsconfig file I can navigate to the file in **vscode** by clicking on component. But Project doesn't run. Please help me if there any issue with my config.

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

Here is my main route file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Login, Movie } from '~/pages';

const AppRouter: React.FC = (props) => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="" element={<Movie />} />
      <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

When I click on component it goes to the file successfully. But when I run the project. It show me error message

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~/pages' in '/Volumes/Workplace/ababa_tech_task/frontend/src/routes'
ERROR in ./src/routes/index.tsx 6:0-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~/pages' in '/Volumes/Workplace/ababa_tech_task/frontend/src/routes'

webpack compiled with 1 error
Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...
Issues checking in progress...
No issues found.
```

It work like this ->

```json
...
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "pages": ["src/pages"]
    },
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Login, Movie } from 'pages'; // pages instead of ~/pages working

const AppRouter: React.FC = (props) => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="" element={<Movie />} />
      <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

But I don't want to keep like this. Because It will confusing. direct module path means comes from node_modules and I want to keep ~/* which means comes from src folder

I used other project with react-rewired-app which worked. but I don't want to do like this.

Comment: Share if there is `tsconfig.base.json`

Answer (score 1):

You gotta check if there's a `"type": "module"` in your package.json, cause then you'll need to write the ext. in every file you import:

```js
import { Login, Movie } from '~/pages.tsx';
```

If that's the case, you can simply remove `"type": "module"`

Comment: There isn't anything like `"type": "module"`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `create-react-app` so you must follow the pattern set by them.

`create-react-app` explains in their documentation how to use [absolute imports](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports) for typescript projects.

If your project looks something like this:

```js
    |- project
    |- src
       |-- components
       |-- pages
            |- index.ts
            |- Login.tsx
            |- Movie.tsx
```

your import should look like this:

```js
    import {Login, Movie} from 'paths'
```

Comment: ```jsx  import {Login, Movie} from 'paths'``` I don't want to use like this because this seems like node_modules. So I want to add something before path

Answer (score 0):

### General fix

I had exactly the same problem.
I think people who have this error are trying to migrate to TypeScript from previously using `js`, `jsx` and have some part of the project written in **TypeScript**, some in **JavaScript**.
After spending some time searching for a possible solution, this one helped me:

***tsconfig.json***

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"],
}
```

Just don't include `"paths"` at all, and you'll be able to absolutely reach your location using `src/...`

### For shadcn UI:

You can replace your `components.json` file content with this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://ui.shadcn.com/schema.json",
  "style": "new-york",
  "rsc": false,
  "tsx": true,
  "tailwind": {
    "config": "tailwind.config.js",
    "css": "src/components/index.css",
    "baseColor": "neutral",
    "cssVariables": true
  },
  "aliases": {
    "components": "src/components",
    "utils": "src/lib/utils"
  }
}
```

And you'll receive the desired result.
I hope that helped!